# Two properties - Second property type depends on first property

Tags: c#, wpf, properties

I have created a class that contains two variables: `Type & Value`. If the first property (`Type`) is filled, the second property (`Value`) can only contain a value that matches the type which is selected on the `Type` property.

```
public class Requirement
{
    public RequirementType Type { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }  

    public enum RequirementType
    {
        OS, NetFramework, Connection
    }             
    public enum OSType
    {
        // Used for RequirementType.OS
        Win, Unix, MacOSX
    }
    public enum NetFrameworkType
    {
        // Used for RequirementType.NetFramework
        Two, Three, Four, FourHalf
    }
    public enum ConnectionType
    {
        // Used for RequirementType.Connection
        Internet, Connected, None
    }  
}
```

I'm using this class in the XAML:

```
<util:Requirement Type="OS" Value="Win" />
```

So for example, if the enum value `OS` has been chosen. The only valid values should be from the enum `OSType`. I started looking in the .Net source how they solved this with the `System.Windows.Trigger` & `System.Windows.Setter` but no success yet.. It seems to be something with the `DependsOn` attribute and `XamlSetTypeConverterAttribute`. Does someone know the solution to this problem?

Comment: And why do you need a single class for this? I'd have 3 classes `OSRequirement`, `NetFrameworkRequirement` and `ConnectionRequirement`

Comment: I'd like to solve it this way. But if it's not possible to realize I'll certainly use that as fallback.

Comment: Why `Value is object`?

Comment: That's a good question how they achieved it for trigger and setter.

Comment: For dynamic Value I don't think enum is the correct approach.  enum is more of a design time thing.    I would use something like Dictionary string, HashSet string

Comment: "I started looking in the .Net source how they solved this with the System.Windows.Trigger & System.Windows.Setter but no success yet." So what did you try already after reading the source?

Comment: Like @weston, I suggest using different classes (that might or might not inherits from a common base class). The reason is simple: in XAML there is no order for attributes: a user could set the `Value` attribute before the `Type` attribute. This also mean that they can be evaluated in any order by the XAML parser.

Comment: @Kryptos Pretty sure that the last point about order can be solved with [`DependsOn("Type")`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.dependsonattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) added to `Value`.

Comment: @weston After adding the `DependsOn` attribute I was wondering where it will retrieve the "right" values from. It looks like it is using the `XamlSetTypeConverterAttribute` and a method for this.

Comment: @sinatr I'm using an `object` because the type varies. It depends on what value is in the `Type` property

Answer (score 1):

You can use a backing field for value and check each type as it's being set.

```
public class Requirement
{
    public RequirementType Type { get; set; }

    private object _value;
    public object Value 
    { 
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if (Type == RequirementType.OS && 
                value.GetType() == typeof(OSType))
            {
                _value = value;
            }
            else 
            {
                throw new Exception("Value type is incorrect for Type provided");
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

This test will throw the exception:

```
var req = new Requirement();
req.Type = RequirementType.OS;
req.Value = RequirementType.Connection;
```

While this second test will properly set the value:

```
var req = new Requirement();
req.Type = RequirementType.OS;
req.Value = OSType.Win;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *normal* properties (type `propful` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>):

```
private RequirementType _type;
public RequirementType Type
{
    get { return _type; }
    set
    {
        _type = value;
        // do whatever logic you want here
    }
}
```